# With two custom post types, single posts in second post type won't display

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created two custom post types in `functions.php`. One is called "Store" and I have `single-store.php` for this post type and another is called "Centre" and I have `single-centre.php` for this post type also. The `single-store.php` display fine, as well the `single.php` too, but the `single-centre.php` won't display at all. All it shows is 404 error page. What was wrong?

Those are the code in functions.php for registering custom post types.

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function stores_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Stores', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Store', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Store:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Stores', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search stores', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No stores found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not stores found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Store', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'store information pages', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'store', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'stores_post_type', 0 );

// Register Custom Post Type
function centres_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Centres', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Centre', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Centre:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Centres', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search centres', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Centre', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'centre information', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 6,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'centre', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'centres_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks? Under Settings .. Permalinks? Sometimes they need to be flushed

Comment: Oh it works now!!! thanks!!!